Issues during git merge with submodule

I wanted to merge and accept all changes from another branch. Why did I get message Automatic merge failed? How to say Git just accept changes from another branch in that case?

git merge --squash --strategy-option theirs anotherbranch
...
<list of files>
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in test/test_lib
...
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD

Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.


After that I tried to abort merge and got There is no merge to abort. How's it possible? A line above Git said me to fix conflict. But actually I did not see conflict marks in my files.

git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).


I tried commit.

git commit -m "merge"

error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.


How can I abort merge in that case?


What does git status say?

I found:
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in tests/test_lib.
Yes, test_lib is a submodule but I tried to clone with --recurse-submodules and without it. It does not matter. And I cannot see any conflict marks in any file.

Use of submodules is a significant info you omitted...

Please do not add important information as a comment. It is better to [edit] question, so other users do not have go though comments to be up to date.

The root cause is a submodule test_lib.
If you see message like that
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in test/test_lib

Use:
git add test_lib
git commit -m "merge"

